# I need to increase a count variable if the sentence does not end with a full stop

Tags: java

Hello guys I am trying to make a basic Lexical analyzer, for that I need to split the string into sentences , if my sentence ends with a full stop it gets split , keeping in mind that sometimes people may not put a full stop at the end of a paragraph , the variable needs still to be increased.

For example:

```
String paragraph="first sentence. second sentence.";
```

count gives 2

but for

`String paragraph="first sentence.second sentence"`

i need the count to be 2

```
for (int start = 0; start < input.length(); start++) {

    if (input.charAt(start) == 46  ) {
        count = count + 1;
    }

}
System.out.print(count+" ");

String[] sentences = input.split("\\.");
 System.out.print(" ");

for (int start = 0; start < count; start++) {

    sentence.add(sentences[start]);

   // sentence.size();
     System.out.print(sentences[start]+"  ");


}
```

Comment: If you split String paragraph="first sentence.second sentence" by dot, then you will get two strings. So, you can return the length of string array that is returned by the split method.

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Comment: Thank you the quesry has been solved by a simple concatenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just count full stops:

```
int count = input.replaceAll("[^.]|\\.$", "").length() + 1;
```

The replace (effectively) deletes all non-dots or a trailing dot.

Comment: actually i want the count to be increased if the sentence doesnt end with a fullstop

Comment: @Vibhor it is increased. See the `+ 1` at the end? If I didn't delete the trailing dot in the content it would be double-counted - that's why it's deleted first and a `1` added at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using a regular expression for this kind of thing.

The JDK has a [`BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/about.html) class for a reason.

> You can analyze four kinds of boundaries with the BreakIterator class:
>   character, word, sentence, and potential line break. When
>   instantiating a BreakIterator, you invoke the appropriate factory
>   method:
>
> getCharacterInstance getWordInstance getSentenceInstance
>   getLineInstance Each instance of BreakIterator can detect just one
>   type of boundary. If you want to locate both character and word
>   boundaries, for example, you create two separate instances.

Answer (score 0):

You can **use String class method endsWith("\.") to check the scentence is ending with .** and then use the split correctly as follows:

```
//Check input scentense ends with . then number of sentences are less  
// than total length of the array
if(input != null && input.endsWith("\\.")) {
   String[] sentences = input.split("\\.");
   count = sentences.length-1;
} 
//else the scentense is NOT ending with . 
// then array length gives the correct count of scentenses
else if(input != null && !input.endsWith("\\.")) {
   String[] sentences = input.split("\\.");
   count = sentences.length;
}
```